# Decodable Json, function doesn't run at all?

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I know this decodable json question has been asked a lot of times, in-fact i was able to do the retreival of data for one of my other projects. However, I cant seem to get this to work. IT is suppose to retrieve the data, decode it and store it. However, my print function was never ran. I don't see the "executed" print and moreover. It does print httpResponse with the headers from the api so I know it is working and it has a response.

Decodable

```
struct GetId: Decodable {
    let id : String?
    let deck_id : String?
    var completed_at : String?
    let created_at : String?
    let locale_key : String?
    let profile_id : String?
    let recommendation_id : String
    let package_id : String?
    let status : String?
    let scoring_scale : String?
}
```

Sample Response

```
{
    "id": "XXXXXXX-XXX-4c6a-XXXX-1XXXXXXX223",
    "deck_id": "career-deck",
    "completed_at": null,
    "created_at": 1551867228744,
    "locale_key": "en-US",
    "profile_id": "XXXXXXX-XXX-4c6a-XXXX-1XXXXXXX223",
    "recommendation_id": null,
    "package_id": null,
    "status": "created",
    "scoring_scale": "NORMAL"
}
```

My function

```
    func requestId()
        {
            let headers = [
                "Authorization": "Basic XXXxxxxXXxxXXXXxxxXXX:x",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "cache-control": "no-cache"
            ]
            let parameters = ["deck_id": "career-deck"] as [String : Any]
            let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.traitify.com/v1/assessments")! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)

            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = (postData as! Data)

            //let session = URLSession.shared
            //let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                    print(httpResponse)
                    if let getIdd = try? JSONDecoder().decode([GetId].self, from: data!){
                    getId = getIdd
                    print(getId[0].id)
                    print("executed")
                }
                }
            }
            task.resume()

        }
```

Comment: Use `do catch` to debug function that can throws with `try`, you can't debug the error if you are using `if let` and `try?`, try to use that so you can understand the error yourself

Comment: I changed it to a try catch kinda thing, there was no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, `created_at` is not a string (it is a numeric value) and `recommendation_id` needs to be optional (like all the other fields).

Also, your example is a single record, but you are decoding an array of objects. Change the decode to be `JSONDecoder().decode(GetId.self, from: data!)`

Comment: Hey, I fixed that, thanks for pointing it out. However, it still isn't working. My print(executed) line isn't in my log

Comment: when i change it to a single record i would have to change my var getID from  = [GetId]() to GetId() However im getting the error cannot invoke initializer for type 'GetId' with no arguments

Comment: However after i initialize everything to empty array the error went away and was manage to get my data. Thanks!